# Populating array from list; doesn't read item if no carriage return

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

I am reading items into an array and then printing them out. What I have noticed is that if the last item in the list has no carriage return it does not become part of the array. Same thing happens if there is only one item in the list.

```
# Read the file in parameter and fill the array named "array"
getArray() {
    local i=0
    array=() # Clear array
    while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
    do
        array+=( "$line" ) # Append line to the array

    done < "$1"
}

getArray "list.txt"

#display array elements
for e in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo $e
done
```

list.txt contains the following:

yellow

green

brown

If there is no carriage return after brown, e.g., brown will not be part of the array. Anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Second, assuming you mean newline, `brown` indeed shouldn't be included because `read` returns 1, breaking the while loop. According to [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html): "The value (exit status) of read is 1 when an end-of-file is encountered. ..." So no good when you have a file like that.

Comment: There might be a hacky way to do what you want (I thought for a minute but can't think of any), but may I ask you why do you use files like that? Text files without newline at the end can be considered illegal in a sense. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file. (For instance, if you do `wc -l` on your file you'll get `2`, because line not terminated by a newline is not really a line.)

Comment: I work in an environment where we support *nix servers using powershell and BMC's network shell. Our main machines unfortunately are Windows and we can only use the tools that we are given. Usually server lists are created in notepad where a carriage return separates each hostname

Comment: On Windows newline is `CRLF`. I don't know how *nix utilities handle DOS files on Windows; do they recognize the DOS newline format, or do they treat CR as a regular character (as it happens when you work with DOS files on *nix)? Anyway, text files should end with a newline, that's a universal truth, regardless of newline being LF or CRLF... Maybe check for the last character in the file first, and append a newline if it's missing? (Last character can be checked via `tail -c1`.)

Comment: Better yet, instruct your text editor to append missing newline on save. I'm not sure if this is possible on Notepad though. (Just to show you a real world example, on Emacs there is a variable `require-final-newline` to control this.)

Answer (score 0):

The hacky solution is to accept non-empty lines that don't end in a newline character.

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
```

However, you can use the `mapfile` module to both replace the loop *and* deal with data with trailing newline characters.

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
array=("${(f@)${mapfile[list.txt]%$'\n'}}")
```